# Bash ping script file in android terminal

Tags: android, bash, loops, terminal, ping

I have small code for ping in a loop:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
_count=0
_target="dns.google.com"
echo "target :: $_target"
while true;
do
_time="$(date +%H%M%S)"
_count=$((_count + 1))
    echo "::::::::::::::::::LOOP"
    echo "time :: $_time"
    echo "counter :: $_count"
    ping -w 1 -c 1 $_target >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    echo "$? ... is reachable" ||
    echo "$? ... is down"
done
```

I'm calling this from android terminal (using SManager).
It should check host availability with a ping in a loop.
The problem is that I get a real response only for the first ping and all the others are bad (output):

```
$ /system/bin/sh /storage/emulated/0/pinger.sh
target :: dns.google.com
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 174912
counter :: 1
0 ... is reachable
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 174912
counter :: 2
1 ... is down
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 174913
counter :: 3
1 ... is down
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 174914
counter :: 4
1 ... is down
.
..
...etc.
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Lukas

EDIT 2:

New script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
_count=0
_target="dns.google.com"
echo "target :: $_target"
while true;
do
_time="$(date +%H%M%S)"
_count=$((_count + 1))
    echo "::::::::::::::::::LOOP"
    echo "time :: $_time"
    echo "counter :: $_count"
    ping -w 1 -c 1 $_target
done
```

Output:

```
$ /system/bin/sh /storage/emulated/0/pinger.sh
target :: dns.google.com
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 205444
counter :: 1
PING dns.google.com (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dns.google (8.8.4.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=7.40 ms

--- dns.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.404/7.404/7.404/0.000 ms
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 205445
counter :: 2
PING dns.google.com (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- dns.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
::::::::::::::::::LOOP
time :: 205447
counter :: 3
PING dns.google.com (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- dns.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
.
..
...etc.
```

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post images of output. It would be really useful if you removed the redirection to `/dev/null` so that we can see what ping is actually returning.

Comment: The same happens (100% packet loss) if I kill the script and run it immediately again. There must be a time delay (not sure how long, maybe about 10 seconds) to get the real response (0% packet loss).

Comment: Have you tried not relying on a third party service? Try pinging localhost instead, then at least you know what the behaviour *should* be.

Comment: Localhost is replying without problem. Can we say the script is OK and the problem is probably in my local vpn solution (no-root firewall)?